# jasmine angular testing - is it possible to add a attribute on a describe method?

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, jasmine

I am new to jasmine testing and coming from a xUnit .Net background.

Is it possible to label a test or a suite of tests in such a fashion:

```
[SomeAttribute]

 describe("A suite", function() {
   it("contains spec with an expectation", function() {
           expect(true).toBe(true);   
             });
 });
```

Does jasmine support [any sort of attributes or identifiers](https://xunit.github.io/docs/comparisons.html)? My goal really is to run a describe group of tests twice, with a different setting between test runs. I did not want to duplicate the tests. Is it possible for a test to kick off other tests?

This question is assuming that I am satisfied with duplicating a build step to run the test suit twice, just with a subset of tests for the second run.

Edit: More realistic example of how I would hope to consume it

```
[Theory]
[TestData(true)]
[TestData(false)]
 describe("A suite", function() {

    beforeEach(() => {
     configureTestBed(/*someHow get input*/);
    });

   it("contains spec with an expectation", function() {
           expect(true).toBe(true);   
             });
 });
```

Comment: Where will setting come from? From an external file? from `karma.conf`? etc?

Comment: Added an edit to the OP to show how I would hope to consume it, again taking inspiration from parameterised test theories: https://andrewlock.net/creating-parameterised-tests-in-xunit-with-inlinedata-classdata-and-memberdata/

If I could specify a different karma.conf that could potentially work as well if I can somehow from a test bed configuration read that setting (and then settle on having duplicate build steps to run the test suite twice and then white list certain describes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is to define separate functions which will accept parameters from somewhere else in your code.

Something like this would do:

```
describe('Sample describe', () => {
    testFunction(1);
});

function testFunction(param1) {
    it('should execute test with params', () => {
        console.log(param1);
        expect(param1).toBe(1);
    });
}
```